# How can one iterate through the subfolders of a subfolder of a shared mail inbox folder?

Tags: vba, outlook

Building up on this one, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63953779/how-to-check-if-data-is-already-in-the-worksheet-when-exporting-email-data-to-wo), how can one iterate through the subfolders of a subfolder of the inbox folder of a shared mailbox?

I'm failing to find a solution so far.

Hopefully we'll find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Defining:

```
Option Explicit

Sub inbox_working()
   
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim Sht As Excel.Worksheet

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
   
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
   
Dim olRecip As Outlook.Recipient
Set olRecip = olNs.CreateRecipient("exampleEmail@email.com") ' Update email
   
Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set Inbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecip, olFolderInbox)
```

And:

```
Dim InboxSubfolder as Outlook.Folder
Set InboxSubfolder = Inbox.Folders("NameOfSubfolder")
```

And then calling the LoopFolders InboxSubfolder, will iterate through the subfolders of the InboxSubfolder.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will create a dictionary of the folder structure from your defined base folder which you can then manipulate

```
Sub RecurseFolderStructure()
    ' Requires Reference: Microsoft Scripting Runtime

    Dim ThisNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace: Set ThisNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder: Set Inbox = ThisNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Dim Junk As Outlook.MAPIFolder: Set Junk = ThisNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderJunk)
    
    Dim BaseFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder: Set BaseFolder = Inbox '.Folders("SubFolder1\SubFolder2...")
    Dim Folders As Scripting.Dictionary: Set Folders = New Scripting.Dictionary
    AddSubFolders BaseFolder, Folders
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    For Each Key In Folders
        'Further Code; for eg.
        Debug.Print Key, Folders(Key)
    Next Key
    
    Folders.RemoveAll
    Set Folders = Nothing
End Sub

Function AddSubFolders(CurrentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, dict As Scripting.Dictionary)
    Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    If Not dict.Exists(CurrentFolder.FolderPath) Then dict.Add CurrentFolder.FolderPath, CurrentFolder
        
    If CurrentFolder.Folders.Count > 0 Then
        For Each Folder In CurrentFolder.Folders
            AddSubFolders Folder, dict
        Next
    End If
End Function
```